# How to merge two large numpy arrays if slicing doesn't resolve memory error?

Tags: python, numpy, data-analysis

I have two numpy arrays `container1` and `container2` where `container1.shape = (900,4000)` and `container2.shape = (5000,4000)`. Merging them using `vstack` results in a `MemoryError`. After searching through the old questions posted here, I tried to merge them using `slicing` like this:

```
mergedContainer = numpy.vstack((container1, container2[:1000]))
mergedContainer = numpy.vstack((mergedContainer, container[1000:2500]))
mergedContainer = numpy.vstack((mergedContainer, container[2500:3000]))
```

but after this even if I do:

```
mergedContainer = numpy.vstack((mergedContainer, container[3000:3100]))
```

it results in `MemoryError`.

I am using `Python 3.4.3 (32-Bit)` and would like to resolve without shifting to `64-Bit`.

Comment: How much RAM do you have and how much of it are you currently using? The merged array should only need about 95 MB (assuming you're using the int32 datatype). (You can use `np.who()` to see the arrays you have in memory.)

Comment: @ajcr I have got 4 GB RAM in my PC.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Every time you call `np.vstack` NumPy has to allocate space for a brand new array.
So if we say 1 row requires 1 unit of memory

```
np.vstack([container, container2])
```

requires *an additional* `900+5000` units of memory.  Moreover, before the assignment occurs,
Python needs to hold space for the old `mergedContainer` (if it exists) as well
as space for the new `mergedContainer`. So building `mergedContainer`
iteratively with slices actually requires more memory than trying to build it
with a single call to `np.vstack`.

Building it iteratively:

```
| total | mergedContainer | container1 | container2 | temp |                                                                      |
|-------+-----------------+------------+------------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  7800 |            1900 |        900 |       5000 |    0 | mergedContainer = np.vstack((container1, container2[:1000]))         |
| 11200 |            3400 |        900 |       5000 | 1900 | mergedContainer = np.vstack((mergedContainer, container[1000:2500])) |
| 13200 |            3900 |        900 |       5000 | 3400 | mergedContainer = np.vstack((mergedContainer, container[2500:3000])) |
```

Building it from a single call to np.vstack:

```
| total | mergedContainer | container1 | container2 | temp |                                                       |
|-------+-----------------+------------+------------+------+-------------------------------------------------------|
| 11800 |            5900 |        900 |       5000 |    0 | mergedContainer = np.vstack((container1, container2)) |
```

---

We can do even better, however. Instead of calling `np.vstack`
repeatedly, **allocate all the space that is needed *once* from
the very beginning** and write the contents of both `container1` and
`container2` into it. In other words, avoid allocating two disparate arrays
`container1` and `container2` if you know eventually you want to merge them.

```
container = np.empty((5900, 4000))
```

Note that [basic slices such as `container[:900]` always return views](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing), and views require
essentially no additional memory. So you could define `container1` and
`container2` like this:

```
container1 = container[:900]   
container2 = container[900:]
```

and then assign values *in place*. This modifies `container`:

```
container1[:] = ...              
container2[:] = ...
```

Thus your your memory requirement would stay around 5900 units.

---

For example,

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(2015)

container = np.empty((5, 4), dtype='int')
container1 = container[:2]   
container2 = container[2:]   
container1[:] = np.random.randint(10, size=(2,4))
container2[:] = np.random.randint(1000, size=(3,4))
print(container)
```

yields

```
[[  2   2   9   6]
 [  8   5   7   8]
 [112  70 487 124]
 [859   8 275 936]
 [317 134 393 909]]
```

while only requiring space for one array of shape (5, 4), and temporarly-used space for the random arrays.

Thus, you wouldn't have to change very much in your code to save memory. Just set it up with

```
container = np.empty((5900, 4000))
container1 = container[:900]   
container2 = container[900:]
```

and then use

```
container1[:] = ...
```

instead of

```
container1 = ...
```

to assign values *in-place*. (Or, of course, you could just write directly into `container`.)

Comment: I just found that if I delete a column from container it still appears in container1 or container2. Isn't that against views?

Comment: Views hold a reference to the shared underlying array -- before modifying `container`, `container1.base is container` should be `True` for example. If you redefine `container` to a slice of `container` (thus "deleting" a column), it becomes a view of the original underlying array, and `container.base` may equal the original `container`. So `container`, `container1`, `container2` all still hold references to the original `container`. Thus rebinding `container` to a new value does not affect `container1` or `container2`.

Comment: How is your solution of assigning in place better than a single `vstack` call? Either way, it's allocating space for the new large array once.

Comment: @sudo: `container1` requires, say, `A` bytes of space. `container2` requires `B` bytes. `vstack([container1, container2])` will require `A+B` bytes. So you would need `2*(A+B)` bytes of space total. If instead you allocate `container` (which requires `A+B` bytes), then define `container1` and `container2` as [views](http://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/ViewsVsCopies.html) of `container`, then they will require zero additional space. So now you would only need `A+B` bytes total.

Comment: @unutbu Oh, I thought we were assuming `container1` and `container2` already exist, and we want to concat them. You're saying that they don't, so we'll make them views from the start. Got it.