# How to convert numpy int to float with separate numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, out-of-memory

I have a huge data of numpy memory error problem, 
I try to use slicing to handle it like following
[How to merge two large numpy arrays if slicing doesn't resolve memory error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31268998/how-to-merge-two-large-numpy-arrays-if-slicing-doesnt-resolve-memory-error)

Slicing is work for numpy.multiply, but it seems no way to convert numpy int to float with slicing. 
Following is sample:

```
images = numpy.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
images[0:5] = images[0:5].astype(numpy.float32)
print type(images[0])
images = images.astype(numpy.float32)
print type(images[0])

<type 'numpy.int32'>
<type 'numpy.float32'>
```

Once I use images.astype(numpy.float32), I got memory error(dtype is same). 
Target memory is too small, and I may hard to use sparse matrix.

Thanks for any suggestion...!

Comment: numpy states that every element of `numpy.array` are of the same type, so you cannot change type of only a part of an array. you could create another array `images_5_float = images[0:5].astype(numpy.float32)`

Comment: ok... got it... I guess that already.., just hope to find another way, thanks your response!

Comment: but if you can do the next operations part-by-part, slice-by-slice , you can use this new partial array

Answer (score 14):

You can't modify the `dtype` of a slice only. When you do

```
images[0:5] = images[0:5].astype(numpy.float32)
```

`images[0:5].astype(numpy.float32)` creates a `float` copy of your slice, but the result is converted back to `int` when assigned back to the `images` slice since `images` is of `dtype` `int`.

What you could do is create a temporary copy of your slice and convert it to float:

```
copied_slice = images[0:5].astype(numpy.float32)
```

do all the computation you need on this smaller part of your data, save whatever result you need, then move on to the next (copied and converted) slice.

Comment: Why it throws me this `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'astype'` @Julien ?

Comment: @andreagalle maybe you are slicing too much and are pulling out a single int instead of a numpy array