# Memory error issue in Python when using hstack

Tags: python, scipy

I am trying to combine all the features which are vectorized with one another. A few of these features are represented as sparse matrices. I get an error when I use hstack to combine all the features.

Code:

```python
from scipy.sparse import hstack
a_train = hstack((categories_one_hot_train, sub_categories_one_hot_tr, text_bow_train, price_standardized_tr,title_bow_train))

a_test  = hstack((categories_one_hot_test, sub_categories_one_hot_test, text_bow_test, price_standardized_test,title_bow_test))

b_train = hstack((categories_one_hot_train, sub_categories_one_hot_tr,text_tfidf_train, price_standardized_tr,title_tfidf_train))

b_test  = hstack((categories_one_hot_test, sub_categories_one_hot_test,text_tfidf_test, price_standardized_test,title_tfidf_test))

c_train = hstack((categories_one_hot_train , sub_categories_one_hot_tr,avg_w2v_vectors_train, price_standardized_tr,avg_w2v_vectors_title_train))

c_test  = hstack((categories_one_hot_test , sub_categories_one_hot_test,avg_w2v_vectors_test, price_standardized_test,avg_w2v_vectors_title_test))

d_train = hstack((categories_one_hot_train, sub_categories_one_hot_tr,tfidf_w2v_vectors_train, price_standardized_tr,tfidf_w2v_vectors_title_train))

d_test  = hstack((categories_one_hot_test, sub_categories_one_hot_test,tfidf_w2v_vectors_test, price_standardized_test,tfidf_w2v_vectors_title_test))
```

Error message:

```
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-55-b8d41d748e49> in <module>()
     17 set2_test  = hstack((categories_one_hot_test, sub_categories_one_hot_test,text_tfidf_test, price_standardized_test,title_tfidf_test))
     18 #set3 avg word2vec
---> 19 set3_train = hstack((categories_one_hot_train , sub_categories_one_hot_tr,avg_w2v_vectors_train, price_standardized_tr,avg_w2v_vectors_title_train))
     20 set3_test  = hstack((categories_one_hot_test , sub_categories_one_hot_test,avg_w2v_vectors_test, price_standardized_test,avg_w2v_vectors_title_test))
     21 #set4 tfidf word2vec

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/sparse/construct.py in hstack(blocks, format, dtype)
    463 
    464     """
--> 465     return bmat([blocks], format=format, dtype=dtype)
    466 
    467 

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/sparse/construct.py in bmat(blocks, format, dtype)
    572         for j in range(N):
    573             if blocks[i,j] is not None:
--> 574                 A = coo_matrix(blocks[i,j])
    575                 blocks[i,j] = A
    576                 block_mask[i,j] = True

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/sparse/coo.py in __init__(self, arg1, shape, dtype, copy)
    190             self.data = self.data.astype(dtype, copy=False)
    191 
--> 192         self._check()
    193 
    194     def reshape(self, *args, **kwargs):

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/sparse/coo.py in _check(self)
    272         idx_dtype = get_index_dtype(maxval=max(self.shape))
    273         self.row = np.asarray(self.row, dtype=idx_dtype)
--> 274         self.col = np.asarray(self.col, dtype=idx_dtype)
    275         self.data = to_native(self.data)
    276 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
    490 
    491     """
--> 492     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
    493 
    494 

MemoryError:
```

Where did I go wrong?

If I cannot resolve this error, are there any other functions which are used to combine sparse matrices with ordinary matrices after encoding data, so that I can build a model on them.

Comment: Can you recreate the error on example data or is it just a problem with your data?

Answer (score 0):

As the error stated, your RAM is not large enough to stack these dataframes on top of each other in this matter. I am assuming that these are extremely large datasets and when you call them in this fashion you are loading all of the data at once, which your current computer cannot handle.

So to answer your question you went wrong by trying to load in all of this data in one step, rather than using batch loading or some [fancy manipulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31268998/how-to-merge-two-large-numpy-arrays-if-slicing-doesnt-resolve-memory-error) seen in this post.

The main reason you are seeing this is because you are repeatedly calling `categories_one_hot_train` and `sub_categories_one_hot_tr`into your program and allocating memory for it. Depending on the size of these dataframes, it could very easily cause a memory error since Python will allocate memory for each instance that is it called it.

A better method (to try, without any information about your data or how much memory each dataset takes up it is impossible to know if you have enough memory to even read in this data) would be to call `categories_one_hot_train` and `sub_categories_one_hot_tr` once and build all of your dataframes (a_train through d_test) as one giant dataframe. Afterwards, you can slice your dataframe based on the columns you need to get the sub-dataframes.

Using this method, you are only calling `categories_one_hot_train` and `sub_categories_one_hot_tr` once rather than 8 times, so Python will only need to allocate the memory for these Dataframes once rather than 8 times.

And if that doesn't work, then it may be best to do the training and test on a subset of the data to avoid running out of memory.